# PHP errors shows orange table and 'call stack'

Tags: php

Recently, if I have PHP errors on my localhost, I'm seeing this layout of an orange table and call stack:

[image: PHP error]
<sub>(source: [doheth.co.uk](http://www.doheth.co.uk/files/phperror.jpg))</sub>

Is this caused by something in particular, a PHP module maybe? Or is it now part of PHP by default? I'd like to go back to the simpler plain message. I'm running PHP on Apache 2 on my Ubuntu desktop.

Comment: You should consider sticking with those error messages - they are pretty handy.

Comment: They're not any better than the standard PHP error output, IMO. In fact I find them harder to read.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

That's the [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) output. You can remove the Xdebug library from the `extension` settings in `php.ini` and it will show the default PHP stack traces or you can set `xdebug.default_enable` to `Off` and it will disable the Xdebug stack traces.

Comment: Nice suggestion! I've added 'xdebug.default_enable = Off' at the end of the [xdebug] extension and did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it comes as a default-setting with xampp. Searched a lot to get rid of this kind of formated error messages. In my case there was no entry `xdebug.default_enable` in my default `php.ini`-file, so I had to *paste it in* to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `xdebug.mode` doesn't contain `develop`. So for me, my `xdebug.mode` was...

`xdebug.mode = debug,develop,coverage`

And changing it to the following got rid of the orange stack traces for me:

`xdebug.mode = debug,coverage`

Without having to turn off or disable the extension.